# Грамматическая основа в предложении "Это была модель гроба"

Tags: синтаксис

Какая грамматическая основа в предложении:

Это была искусно сделанная модель гроба.

Answer (score 4):

Это была искусно сделанная модель гроба.

Это было что? Это была модель. Это - подлежащее, была модель - сказуемое. Модель какая?- гроба  - определение со значением дополнения.
Связка "была" согласуется в роде с существительным именного сказуемого. Употреблён именительный падеж вместо творительного: это было моделью гроба. Такая модель двусоставного предложения часто используется в речи. Это есть модель...Это будет модель...Это была модель...

В назывном было бы "Вот модель". Связка "был", "была" указывает на именное сказуемое двусоставного предложения.

Comment: "Это  была  модель  гроба"  и  "это  было  моделью  гроба"  не  равноценны  по  смысловым  акцентам.  В  первом  случае  главное  "модель",  а  во  втором  "это".

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать подлежащим ЭТО, сказуемое БЫЛА МОДЕЛЬ не совпадет с ним в роде.

Comment: Это шкаф. Получается, что это назывное предложение?

Comment: >Если сделать подлежащим ЭТО, сказуемое БЫЛА МОДЕЛЬ не совпадет с ним в роде.  
  
Да. Хотя "это" в принципе не требует согласования. Но штука в том, что при этом идёт согласование с моделью. Если наши оппоненты правы (с точки зрения "современных" подходов), то грамматисты, похоже, окончательно запутались.

Comment: >Это шкаф. Получается, что это назывное предложение?  
  
У кого получается? Я так полагаю, что здесь пропущен глагол-связка. Остальное - все так же.

Answer (score -1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то в школе сейчас учат, что предложение односоставное, "была модель" - основной член, составное именное сказуемое. Но тут, боюсь, найдется о чем поспорить. 
При некотором желании, модель можно записать и в подлежащие. 
Интересно, что скажут профессионалы. По поводу одной похожей фразы мы совсем недавно не на шутку поспорили, так и не договорились, упершись, как я понимаю, в терминологию.

*Оффтоп. Долго думал над своей конструкцией "записать и в подлежащие". Вроде все по-русски, а глаз режет, нет?*

Comment: А мне хочется сделать подлежащим ЭТО, а сказуемым БЫЛА МОДЕЛЬ...

Comment: Согласна..

Comment: Мне тоже чего-то "хочется". Я ж об этом не говорю. 
Вы лучше скажите, в школе так сейчас учат?

Comment: Это - подлежащее. Посмотрите учебники, сайты, где говорится об указательных местоимениях.

Comment: Посмотрите сами. Потом расскажете.

Comment: А я и так знаю.  А Вы даже в объеме школьной программы не умеете разобрать.А всех учить беретесь.

Comment: Чего-то темы пошли какие-то замогильные)))) То "когда я рожусь баобабом", то "модель гроба"... )))))))))))))))

Comment: Раз непонятно из ответа Людмилы,  пишу четко: да, в школе учат (и учили) так. По крайней мере, лет тридцать.